# How to set selected range in range selector in dygraph

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

By default, dygraph select the whole date range in its range selector:

[image]

Is there an option to set the default selected range in dygraph? I've been searching for a while and can't find any similar problem as mine.

This is my desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought you can only pass int values on `dateWindow` options of dygraph. It seems like it accepts `Date` object as well. I solved my issued by adding `dateWindow` option:

```
new Dygraph(document.getElementById('#graph'), data, {
     labels: [ "x", "y" ],
     showRangeSelector: true,
     legend: 'always',
     dateWindow: [new Date("2021-06-01"), new Date("2021-06-25")]
});
```

NOTE: I'm changing the value of date object dynamically